# I see the word SELAH in the name MethuSELAH. I don't see 'selah' definition in 'Methuselah' definition, though. Is there a connection?

Tags: definition

The definitions of SELAH and MethuSELAH seem unrelated to each other; please help me understand.
**SELAH** definition includes (Hebrew)'to lift up, exalt', 'forever', 'pause for contemplation'; (NLT) 'interlude'.
**MethuSELAH** name meaning (Hebrew) 'a man holding a spear'; 'his death shall bring judgement'. Logic seems to indicate a connection, unless I'm missing something. Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

**There is not connection between  SELAH and MethuSELAH**.

In English, it looks like selah is in Methuselah,
מְתוּשֶׁ֖לַח
, but in Hebrew it is a different spelling. Actually, the letter transliterated "L" is the only letter in common the other to letters (consonants) are different Hebrew letters transliterated with the same Roman characters.

Compare:

שֶׁ֖ and סֶ֫ transliterated as *se*

ח and ה transliterated as *h*.

**Selah**

There is a debate over the meaning of Selah. Even the Jewish Publication Society does not translate it:

```
  O LORD, my foes are so many! 
  Many are those who attack me; 
     many say of me, 
     “There is no deliverance for him through God.” 
                                                Selah. 
-- Jewish Publication Society. (1985). Tanakh: 
   The Holy Scriptures (Psalm 3:2–3).
```

They add the footnote to Selah, "*A litergical direction of uncertain meaning*."

BDB defines it:

> סֶ֫לָה ... vb. *lift up* (voices in ברוך לעולם), *or exalt* (לעולם י׳) (Imv. of סָלַל ...
> --
> Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon (p. 699). Clarendon Press.

Based on the root:

> סָלַל ...] vb. *lift up, cast up*
> --
> Ibid. p. 699.

However, another possible root is:

> סָלַח ... vb. *forgive, pardon* ( סְלַח id., NH סְלִיחָה *forgiveness*); ...
> --
> Ibid., p. 699.

As well as other possible homonyms of these two roots.  This was apparently a musical/liturgical change in how to sing the song at that point.  However, we no longer know what that direction was.

Selah doesn't affect how we interpret the psalm.  It instructed how the psalm was recited.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p96RVPukpQk

**Methuselah**

> †מְתוּשֶׁ֫לַח ... n.pr.m. descendant of Seth (? man of the dart: more prob. Bab.; see conj. in HomPSBA 1893, 243 ff.);—מ׳ Gn 5:22, 25, 26, 27 (P), 1 Ch 1:3, מְתוּשָׁ֑לַח Gn 5:21 (P).  Μαθουσαλα.
> -- Ibid., p. 607.

Meth:

> מַת ... n.m. *male, man* (מְתוּ־ in n.pr.; Zinj. מת coll. *males, male offspring*; Assyrian mutu, husband; Ethiopic ምት: (mət) id.; cf. Egyptian m-t, phallus, male, ...
> -- Ibid., p. 607.

Selah:

Verb root:

> שָׁלַח ... vb. *send*
> --
> Ibid., p. 1018.

Noun:

> שֶׁ֫לַח ... n.[m.] *missile, weapon, sprout*
> -- Ibid., p. 1019.

Comment: Good answer. +1.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Webb. I appreciate the time and care you took to thoroughly explain! BV Smith